# Migrate SQL Server 2014 Enterprise to new machine

Tags: windows-server-2012, sql-server

We had Bizspark, which we are now graduates of.  As I understand from the Bizspark page:

> You can keep, at no charge, all the software you downloaded, including a standard configuration of Windows Server and Microsoft SQL Server.

I currently have SQL Server 2014 Enterprise 12.0.2000.8 installed from our Bizspark package on my local developer machine.  I would like to move this to another computer.  Is this possible/permitted?  And if so, how would I go about it?

Using product key recovery software, the version of SQL Server I have installed has no product key but it does have a product ID.  This is expected when downloading from MSDN.

Comment: The ISO is not available from our MSDN subscription any more because we've graduated.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm so confused, we used to be able to download anything we wanted from Bizspark, but since we've graduated we're unable to as our subscription ended.  So I'm not sure how we can migrate one installation to another computer when the current installations don't seem to have any product keys.

Comment: @Ramhound I mean Bizspark... we are/were a business startup.

Comment: Bizspark access is for 3 years, and you "Graduate" after the three years.  I think you're getting confused with the "Graduate" term which is used both in Bizspark and Dreamspark.  A Bizspark graduate has some benefits (continued usage of downloaded software).

Comment: I am not sure the reason I read the question in a different way.  After your explanation the first sentence seems to be crystal clear.

Comment: @Ramhound, glad it's cleared up :)  Any ideas on transferring software to a new computer without the original install files and no product key?

Comment: The product key isn't exactly a problem.  There is software to determine the key ( there are tons of questions on that subject ) getting an installation disk is entirely different.  I would try the Trial version and see if there is an opportunity to provide a license key.

Comment: @Ramhound, used key finding software, no product key exists for the installation.  I am assuming it was a special ISO that didn't require one.

Comment: Even if the license was embedded it should still be registered.

Comment: @ramhound what tools could I use to try and get the license out to be reused?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the product key is embedded into the installer, so you do need the ISO
and cannot install without it.

If you have not kept that ISO, you could maybe virtualize the computer and use it
elsewhere as a virtual machine. You will need a Physical-to-Virtual (P2V) product
that preserves the hardware, or you risk deactivation.

I have had in the past good success in that domain with the free
[VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter).
To run the VM you will need the free version of VMware Player.

I note that Bizspark licenses seem to run for a maximum of three years.

Comment: "I note that Bizspark licenses seem to run for a maximum of three years." This is clearly not true... Please update the answer - https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/about/graduation.aspx

Comment: @milanio: The contract runs for 3 years, afterwards conditions and the contract changes to MSDN : "Once you complete the graduation process, you will get a license to keep, at no charge, most of the software you downloaded during the three years you were in the BizSpark program. However, [...] Visual Studio 2013 and later [...] will need to renew their MSDN subscription for each user running Visual Studio after graduation". MSDN subscriptions are costly.

Comment: my point only was that the sentence "Bizspark licenses run for maximum 3 years" is misleading - the licenses you get from BizSpark (after you graduate) are for production use and they stay valid forever not only for 3 years, aren't they? This has nothing to do with MSDN subscription(s). Actually, as you pointed out, MSDN subscription is what you lose after 3 years.

Comment: @milanio: The poster has graduated *after 3 years, so is no longer on BizSpark*, His SQL Server serial is maybe still valid but is certainly not usable without the original ISO which, having graduated, he cannot download any more. I also have no idea if this serial can be transferred to another computer. If it is not transferable, installing SQL Server in contravention may cause Microsoft to void that serial. All in all, I note above that keeping the current computer as a VM is one safe path to new hardware. I don't see anything wrong or inexact about that.